# Change on controller's attribute does not affect view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new in Angular and I'm facing a little problem. Here is the deal:

Having already declared a module with the name "myMod" I'm defining a directive is this manner:

```
myMod.directive("myDirective", function () {
    dir = {
        restrict:'A',
        template: '<h3>{{myController.name}}</h3> <span class="button">Click to change name</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $(element).find('.button').click(function(){
                scope.changeName('John'); // I found this way to call my controller's function 
            });
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            this.name = 'Michael';
            var self = this;

            $scope.changeName = function(newName){
                self.name = newName;
            };
        }],
        controllerAs: 'myController'
    };
    return dir;
})
```

and I'm applying this directive on my html as simple as:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

So, even though initially I get the right view (it renders the name "Michael" correctly) when I press the button, even though the value of the controller's attribute "name" changes to "John" the name on the page still remains "Michael". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer to show a working fiddle.  Here's an example of using the link function and controller function with scope.

```
directive("myDirective", function () {
    dir = {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<h3>{{myController.name}}</h3> <span class="button" ng-click="callController()">Click to change name</span>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.callController = function () {
                scope.changeName('John');
            }
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            this.name = 'Michael';
            var self = this;

            $scope.changeName = function (newName) {
                self.name = newName;
            };
        }],
        controllerAs: 'myController'
    };
    return dir;
}
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nr5c9v1e/1/

Comment: Ok, though this is just an example. I've set up an uploading library on the link function of my directive and I'm trying to call my controller's functions when uploading starts or finishes from the scope of library's callbacks. So, I certainly need this calls to the controller. This is just a simplified example just to state the problem I face